# How to see commits applied to a submodule between two commits of parent repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I have a repository with two submodules:

Foo - sub1
    - sub2

I would like to see the commits applied to each of the submodules by a certain commit.  Is there an easy way to do this?

In case my question isn't clear, in my use case, sub1 and sub2 are tracking the history of a certain branch, so if I were to get the commit-hash of sub1 for commit1 of Foo, and hte commit-hash of commit2 of Foo, and do git log between these commits, I should see some number of in-between commits showing all the changes applied between those commits.  I'd like that info for all the submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git submodule summary` command will give you (most of) what you want.  I'm going to use the [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/) repository as an example, because it has a couple of submodules associated with it.

After pulling some updates:

```
$ git pull
```

I can see that my submodules are now out-of-date:

```
$ git status
On branch devel
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/devel'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  modified:   lib/ansible/modules/core (new commits)
  modified:   lib/ansible/modules/extras (new commits)
```

I can use the `git submodule summary` command to get a summary of
commits between the version of the submodule currently checked out and
the version in the repository:

```
$ git submodule summary lib/ansible/modules/core
* lib/ansible/modules/core 2f46c35...f15000d (46):
  < fix win_user type checking
  < git still needs to have abspath applied to dest
  < Wrap calls to main() with if check
  < handles config replace properly in eos_template
  ...
```

This shows the first line of each commit; if I want detailed
information, I can use the commit range displayed in the first line of
the output (`2f46c35...f15000d`):

```
$ git submodule update
$ cd lib/ansible/modules/core
$ git log 2f46c35...f15000d
```

We update the submodule first, to bring it up to the current commit,
and then just run `git log` in that repository using the commit range
we were given by `git submodule summary`.